# Cayley's formula summation form

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I need to see how

$T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-1}i(n-i){n-1\choose i-1}T_iT_{n-i}$

where $T_n$ denotes number of trees in a complete graph on $n$ vertices.

I have found out that # trees with one fixed edge is equal to

$E_n =\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{n-2 \choose i-1}T_iT_{n-i}$

however I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: If formula for $E_n$ is correct, then let's evaluate in $2$ different ways the number of trees with chosen marked edge. On the one hand it is ${n \choose 2} \cdot E_n$. On the other it is $(n - 1) \cdot T_n$. Unfortunately, there appears an extra factor of $\frac{n}{2i}$ on the right

Comment: Yes, this also gives the result if you play with the sum, I was just trying to figure out a different argument. I thought about the expression $i(n-i)T_i T_{n-i}$ - dividing the n vertices into two sets with $i$ and $n-i$ vertices, there are $T_i$ and $T_{n-i}$ possible trees that can be connected in $i(n-i)$ ways to form a tree for the whole $K_n$. However I am not sure about the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

More straightforward way:

Let's  rewrite $S_1 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-1}i(n-i){n-1\choose i-1}T_iT_{n-i}$ by performing a change $i \mapsto n - i$, giving $S_2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-1}i(n-i){n-1\choose n -i-1}T_iT_{n-i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-1}i(n-i){n-1\choose i}T_iT_{n-i}$.

Now $\frac{1}{2}(S_1 + S_2)$ is just $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2\cdot(n-1)}i(n-i){n\choose i}T_iT_{n-i}$, and we want to prove:

$$T_n \cdot 2\cdot(n - 1) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}i(n-i){n\choose i}T_iT_{n-i} $$
The LHS is the number of spanning trees with chosen oriented edge. So is the RHS, because it is the number of ways to choose $i$ vertices, draw trees of size $i$ and $n - i$ and connect by an edge coming from tree of size $i$ to tree of size $n - i$.

Comment: I don’t think that you get # spanning trees with chosen edge from that. Counting in 2 ways gives $2n^{n-3}$ and the LHS is not equal to that if you use $T_n=n^{n-2}$